# Startup Script in Azure (Like metadata_startup_script in GCP)

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

In GCP while creating a VM using terraform we have this parameter "metadata_startup_script" where we actually set a templatefile (bash script) that runs whenever VM restarts.

This is different than the cloud-init because cloud-init is called only while creating a new VM.

I am looking for an alternate in azure. Can we have this kind of startup-scripts which should run if VM restarts every time.

I found out the custom_data field but I think it only stores the cloud-init config which will only run when VM is created.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: I have not used it currently but seems like it will work, I'll update later.

Comment: Any updates? Do you try it and it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature to set a script that runs whenever VM restarts in Azure Terraform. What you can do is to set a Cron task yourself via the [VM extension](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_extension).

Answer (score 0):

I used the custom data to feed the cloud-init configuration where I defined a systemd unit file of type oneshot made it execute the shell script which i want to run everytime VM restarts.

```
 write_files:
  - path: /etc/systemd/system/testserv.service
    permissions: 0777
    owner: root:root
    content: |
      [Unit]
      Description=One Shot

      [Service]
      ExecStart=/etc/createfile
      Type=oneshot
      RemainAfterExit=yes

      [Install]
      WantedBy=multi-user.target
  - path: /etc/createfile
    permissions: 0777
    owner: root:root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      sudo cat /usr/bin/test-file.txt
      echo 'text here' >> /usr/bin/test-file.txt


runcmd:
  - systemctl enable testserv
  - systemctl start testserv
```